# Laravel drop down multiple values from DB in drop down

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel drop downs is there a way to have multiple values in the drop down value?

Normally you would write a command like this to get a name and your id for the select box.

```
Project::where('project_id', '=', Session::get('project_id'))->lists('project_name', 'id');
```

and it will make a drop down like this

```
<select>
<option value="13">12345</option>
<option value="16">14-100</option>
<option value="17">14-200</option>
<option value="31">987</option>
</select>
```

I want to know if I can some how have it display another value from the db in value like created_by, so it would look something like this.

```
<select class="form-control" name="project">
<option value="13">12345 Billy user</option>
<option value="16">14-100 Sally user</option>
<option value="17">14-200 Thomas user</option>
<option value="31">987 Lola user</option>
</select>
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the fields you need in the controller:

```
$projects = Project::where('project_id', '=', Session::get('project_id'))->get('id', 'project_name', 'created_by');
```

Then pass it to the view:

`return View::make('my.view', array('projects' => $projects))`;

There you create the option tags manually:

```
<select class="form-control" name="project">
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->project_name }} {{ $project->created_by }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple options here.

You can do it directly in the SQL. This will keep everything server side and will not take up any memory or time building models.

```
Project::where('project_id', '=', Session::get('project_id'))
    ->lists(DB::raw('CONCAT(project_name, " ", created_by)'), 'id');
```

However, if your logic is a little more complicated, or you're looking for a more "Laravel-ish" solution, you can create an accessor method on your Project model. With this method, you end up creating all the models before calling the lists method:

```
// model
class Project extends Eloquent {
    // accessor method to provide 'name_by' attribute
    public function getNameByAttribute() {
        return $this->project_name . ' ' . $this->created_by;
    }
}

// if you limit the select, make sure you at least select the fields you need
$projects = Project::select('id', 'project_name', 'created_by')
    ->where('project_id', '=', Session::get('project_id'))
    ->get();
// call lists on the Collection of models, which will allow use of the accessor
$projectList = $projects->lists('name_by', 'id');
```

Docs on Laravel accessors are [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators), if you're interested.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static function tableListToDropDown($tableName='',$nameField='',$idField='')
    {
        if ($idField == null)
        {
            $idField = "id";    
        }

        $listFiledValues = DB::table($tableName)->select($idField,$nameField)->get();
        $selectArray=[];
        foreach ($listFiledValues as $listFiledValue)
        {
            $selectArray[$listFiledValue->$idField] = $listFiledValue->$nameField;
        }

        return $selectArray;
    }
```

Comment: it would provide more value, if you would explain your uncommented code

Comment: This can be used in form builder

Comment: Please do not add such explanation to the comment section, rather edit your answer to contain all relevant information